# Change scope from window to angular view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have to integrate with a vendor that uses an iframe. The JS listens for events emitted by the iframe. In my Angular component.ts I have:

```
ngOnInit() {
 let listener = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
 let listen = window[listener];
 let messageEvent = listener == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
 listen(messageEvent, function(e) {
  if (e.origin == 'someURL') {
    console.log(e.data)
    this.doStuff(e.data);
  }
}, false);
}

doStuff(data){
 //do stuff
}
```

The issue is that when this.processMessage() is called I get an error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.processMessage is not a function
```

I know this is a scope issue since the scope of 'this' is now the window. What is the best way to handle this situation?

Is

```
 let that = this
```

outside of listen() acceptable with es6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to manually create an intermediate variable, TypeScript does that for you when you use an arrow-function:

```
listen(messageEvent, (e) => {
  if (e.origin == 'someURL') {
    console.log(e.data)
    this.doStuff(e.data);
  }
}, false);
```

In the background, it does exactly the same thing, by creating a variable named `_this` when compiling to targets that don't support arrow functions.